# Need help removing canonical rel link from Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8

I need to remove link rel="canonical".  I removed it from the Meta Tag Module and I also used a module that's supposed to remove it but it still remains.

I removed all instances in the Meta Tag module and I also used the Disable Link Rel module that's supposed to remove it.  It's still there.

I need to remove this link from the head of my site.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do from hook_preprocess_html in the $variables['page']['#attached'] array to be altered.
You have to fist check by printing variables

```
print '<pre>';print_r($variables['page']['#attached']);die;
```

After then check and empty the array like this :-

```
if($variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][1][1] == 'canonical_url') { $variables['page']['#attached']['html_head'][1][0]['#attributes'] = array(); }
```

In my case the printed array was like this:-

```
    Array
(
    [html_head] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [#tag] => meta
                            [#attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => title
                                    [content] => test english 1 | localhost
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => title
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [#tag] => link
                            [#attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [rel] => canonical
                                    [href] => http://localhost/leadervinu_development/drupal-8.7.3/en/node/51
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => canonical_url
                )
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm going to give this shot.  I appreciate the help.